# UIKit.framework and CoreGraphics.framework are not found in Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Tags: swift, frameworks, ios8.1, xcode6.1.1

I want to add two frameworks in my project but when i am go to project navigator and select general tab than further gone to Linked Frameworks and Libraries options ***choose frameworks and libraries to add***: 
these Frameworks are not found in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the framework into your project then add it manually.

Go to `Build Phases` > `Link Binary With Libraries` > `+` > `Add Other`.

[image]

Don't forgot to import the frameworks in your swift file.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing problem somedays but no approach is fixed to my problems...
but when i **re-install my Xcode 6.1.1** than all the Frameworks are shows in the list...